# Android AsyncTask null value parameter

Tags: android, android-asynctask, null, android-volley

i've a little problem with my code. 
I'm trying to perform a volley request on doInBackground behaviour and then to use its result to set some layout elements. Here's the async snippet:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Message>

{
    @Override
    protected Message doInBackground(String... params) {
        rm = new RequestManager(MessageDisplay.this);
        idM = params[0];
        retrieveMessage(new VolleyCallbackOp(){
            public void onSuccess(List<Message> ml) {
                m = ml.get(0);
                Log.d("print1", m.getContent());   <---- this is fine
            }
        });
        Log.d("print2", m.getContent());   <---- m always null
        return m;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Message m) {
        super.onPostExecute(m);
        Log.d("messaggio", m.getContent());
        mds = new MessageDisplaySetter(MessageDisplay.this);
        View v = mds.setMessageDisplayInfo(m, 3);
        contentD.addView(v);

                }
            }
        }); 
    }
```

this code is called in activity onCreate():

```
Message m = new Message();
String target2 = i.getExtras().getString("messageId");
            new MyAsyncTask().execute(target2);
```

The problem is that the Log "print2" tell the variable **m** is null while "print1" is ok. 
Have you any tip to pass the result of this request to the related onPostExecute()?

Comment: Can you show the code for you Message object please? (Assuming this is your own object)

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your log for `print2` is null - is because you are in a race condition. By calling `new VolleyCallbackOp` you are doing an **asynchrounous** network call which might take a while to complete. Your code does not wait until it's finished. That's why `print2` is null most of the time.

There are several solutions for your case. One of them is to use the callback mechanism of `onSuccess` and do your logic there.

Comment: I thought onPostExecute() could solve this problem, that's why I used it. I'll build the code there so, thx man ;)